# Overriding the init method in a subclass and calling [super initWith:bla], correct way?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, overriding, superclass, macos

I'm subclassing a class.
I'm overriding a init method. This one: -(id)initWithSomething:(Something*)somet;

this would look like this (in the subclass)

```
-(id)initWithSomething:(Something *)somet with:(int)i{

    if (self = [super init]) {
     //do something   
    }

    return self;
}
```

But now I want to call the init in the superclass too.

How would I now do this? Mayby this way?

```
-(id)initWithSomething:(Something *)somet with:(int)i{

    if (self = [super init]) {

    }

    [super initWithSomething:somet];

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically like this:

```
-(id)initWithTarget:(CCNode *)someTarget
{
    self = [super initWithTarget:someTarget];
    if (self)
    {

    }
    return self;
}
```

It's the responsibility of super to call the vanilla init selector if it needs to.

Answer (score 2):

```
-(id)initWithSomething:(Something *)somet {
    if ((self = [super initWithSomething:somet])) {
      // ...
    }    
    return self;
}
```

One-and-only-one method should be your "designated initializer" for a class. All other initializers should call that one, and the designated initializer should call `super`'s designated initializer. (This is a general rule; there are a few exceptions such as in `initWithCoder:`, but it is the normal approach.)